# Best practices for updating current data Firebase database after adding some more denormalization

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to check on the best and recommended practices for updating current data in a Firebase database after I decide to have some more duplicated data to support some complex querying or just to make it easier to read data. For e.g., I have list of users in my Firebase database and each user look like

```
users
 -KGvMIPwul2dUYABCDEF
   countryCode: 1
   id: -KGvMIPwul2dUYABCDEF
   mobileNumber: 1231231234 
   name: Varun Gupta
```

I have been querying a user based on his mobile number which works with current data. Now, I get a requirement to also query a user based on the combination of the country code and mobile number. So, I decide to add some duplicated data in order to make the query easy and the new user would look like

```
users
 -KGvMIPwul2dUYABCDEF
   countryCode: 1
   id: -KGvMIPwul2dUYABCDEF
   mobileNumber: 1231231234 
   name: Varun Gupta
   mobileNumberWithCC: 11231231234
```

I will have the `mobileNumberWithCC` for all the new users but I also want to update the current users with this information. I want to ask for the best practices for updating the database in such a scenario. Should I just write some code using admin SDK to update the required data and run it once or are there any other suggested ways to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: This is an issue that faces a lot of developers - as your app grows and new features are added there has to be additional data stored. Since this is a straight forward addition of a child node, your conclusion is probably the simplest: iterate over all users, read in the user data, concatenate the fields and write out the additional field. Not sure why anyone would vote to close this question as it is opinion based but directly related a specific coding issue which was laid out very clearly in the question.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @AlexM.I went with something that Jay has suggested which is what I have in mind when I posted the question. I just wanted to make sure that I am not overlooking something.

Answer (score 2):

Create a method like this in which you can update your data at once:

```
private static void updateUser(String userId) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("/users/" + userId + "/", new HashMap<>().put("mobileNumber", 1231231234));
    map.put("/users/" + userId + "/", new HashMap<>().put(mobileNumberWithCC, 11231231234));
    yourReference.updateChildren(map);
}
```

Or even simpler:

`yourReference.child(users).child(userId).child(mobileNumber).setValue(1231231234);`
`yourReference.child(users).child(userId).child(mobileNumberWithCC).setValue(11231231234);`